# List the number of running instances in an AWS region

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-cli

I want to list the number of all running ec2 instances in the us-west-2 region and I was able to list the instances but actually, I want the number of instance names is not nessosry. please see that below code

```
import boto3
ec2client = boto3.client('ec2',region_name='us-west-2')
response = ec2client.describe_instances()
for reservation in response["Reservations"]:
    for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
        if instance['State']['Name'] == 'running':
           x = (instance["InstanceId"])
           print (x)
```

Output is here

[image]

Output type

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store those names in a list, and check the list length:

```
running_instances = []

ec2client = boto3.client('ec2',region_name='us-west-2')
response = ec2client.describe_instances()
for reservation in response["Reservations"]:
    for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
        if instance['State']['Name'] == 'running':
           x = (instance["InstanceId"])
           #print(x)
           running_instances.append(x)
        
print('Number of running instances', len(running_instances))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **filter** to identify running instances.

Using the **Resource** method:

```py
import boto3

ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')

instances = ec2_resource.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}])

# List running instances
for instance in instances:
  print(instance.instance_id)

# Count running instances
count = len(list(instances))
print(f"{count} instances running")
```

Using the **Client** method:

```py
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = ec2_client.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}])

# List running instances
count = 0
for reservation in response["Reservations"]:
    for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
        print(instance["InstanceId"])
        count += 1

# Count running instances
print(f"{count} instances running")
```